# Visual Studio Code - Syntax Errors for functioning PS Script

Tags: powershell

I am new in using Visual Studio Code for editing and debuging powershell scripts and have a problem that the script which is working without Problem in powershell_ise is not working in visual Studio Code.

I get some Syntax Errors althoug the script is a exact copy of Script which is working in powershell_ise.

It gives me Errors like this but i am sure that there is no Syntax Errors.

```
At C:\Scripts\Scripts\PasswordResetLog.ps1:172 char:41
+     sendmail "test@test.com" $mailbody
+                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~
The string is missing the terminator: ".

At C:\Scripts\Scripts\PasswordResetLog.ps1:87 char:1
+ {
+ ~
Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition.
PS C:\Scripts\Scripts>
```

Do you know what should be a reason?
Is it it possible to unassign json debug config file. How to do it?

Comment: If it's an exact copy, then it must be being read differently. And reading a script differently and getting an error about quotes is a particularly common error and says you have Unicode smart quotes in a file saved as UTF-8 and wrongly read as ASCII. Possible fixes: check all your double quotes are `"` (ASCII character 34) not `“` or `”`, check your file encoding is UTF-8 and that Visual Studio Code is reading it as UTF-8. If it's not that, then I can only wonder if it's become corrupted somehow - I corrupted things with VS Code replace when new to it, multiple cursors edit multiple places.

Comment: Also, make sure VS Code is in PowerShell language mode (Ctrl+K, M, then select "PowerShell")

Comment: Hi Mathias...Thanks for your answer..The Encoding is already UTF-8 and powershell ist via user Settings Default Programm...

Comment: Is there any other configuration possibilites which i could check...